# TOra errors on usage of date function

Tags: sql, oracle, tora

I am currently using TOra as a query browser.

When I run the following query, I get an `ORA-00936 missing expression` error. This occurs even though I have set values for the bind variables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    L.LOG_ID,
    L.EVENT_ARG4,
    L.EVENT_TYPE,
    L.EVENT_ARG1,
    L.EVENT_ARG3,
    L.PROD_ITEM_ID,
    TRUNC(L.LOG_DATE) AS LOG_DATE
FROM 
    EVENTLOG L
WHERE 
    L.LOG_DATE >= TO_DATE(:report_start_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AND 
    L.LOG_DATE < TO_DATE(:report_end_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

What would be causing this problem?

Comment: I actually just started using Oracle SQL Developer, so this is no longer an issue for me. Leaving it just in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the colons in your `WHERE` clause.

Your PL-SQL statement should look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    L.LOG_ID,
    L.EVENT_ARG4,
    L.EVENT_TYPE,
    L.EVENT_ARG1,
    L.EVENT_ARG3,
    L.PROD_ITEM_ID,
    TRUNC(L.LOG_DATE) AS LOG_DATE
FROM 
    EVENTLOG L
WHERE 
    L.LOG_DATE >= TO_DATE(report_start_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AND 
    L.LOG_DATE < TO_DATE(report_end_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

Comment: The colons are there to signify that those values are bind variables. When I run the query TOra asks me to define the bind variables. I do that. After that it tries to run the query and that is where I get the error.